# Why does React listen for all events?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a production build of React 18 and I've noticed that vast amount of event listeners listening for all imaginable actions on id="root" element.
Is there a reason for all of them? I'm more than sure that I didn't declare them.
[image]

Comment: you can see the [React Official Document](https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#changes-to-event-delegation) to check `Event Delegation` change

Answer (score 1):

this behavior is not only in `react 18` but `react 17` also . In  `React=>17`    event handlers are no longer attached at the document level. Instead, it will attach them to the root DOM container into which your React tree is rendered **( the div with id='root')**

At runtime, React initializes multiple objects to know how to handle event listeners. if you check **react-dom.development.js** file you'll find An array of all native events that are handled:

```
var simpleEventPluginEvents = ['abort', 'auxClick', 'cancel', 'canPlay', 'canPlayThrough', 'click', 'close', 'contextMenu', 'copy', 'cut', 'drag', 'dragEnd', 'dragEnter', 'dragExit', 'dragLeave', 'dragOver', 'dragStart', 'drop', 'durationChange', 'emptied', 'encrypted', 'ended', 'error', 'gotPointerCapture', 'input', 'invalid', 'keyDown', 'keyPress', 'keyUp', 'load', 'loadedData', 'loadedMetadata', 'loadStart', 'lostPointerCapture', 'mouseDown', 'mouseMove', 'mouseOut', 'mouseOver', 'mouseUp', 'paste', 'pause', 'play', 'playing', 'pointerCancel', 'pointerDown', 'pointerMove', 'pointerOut', 'pointerOver', 'pointerUp', 'progress', 'rateChange', 'reset', 'resize', 'seeked', 'seeking', 'stalled', 'submit', 'suspend', 'timeUpdate', 'touchCancel', 'touchEnd', 'touchStart', 'volumeChange', 'scroll', 'toggle', 'touchMove', 'waiting', 'wheel'];
```

and also you'll find A function  that does a mapping between the native events and the event handlers properties:

```
function registerSimpleEvent(domEventName, reactName) {
      topLevelEventsToReactNames.set(domEventName, reactName);
      registerTwoPhaseEvent(reactName, [domEventName]);
    }
    function registerSimpleEvents() {
      for (var i = 0; i < simpleEventPluginEvents.length; i++) {
        var eventName = simpleEventPluginEvents[i];
        var domEventName = eventName.toLowerCase();
        var capitalizedEvent = eventName[0].toUpperCase() + eventName.slice(1);
        registerSimpleEvent(domEventName, 'on' + capitalizedEvent);
      } // Special cases where event names don't match.

      registerSimpleEvent(ANIMATION_END, 'onAnimationEnd');
      registerSimpleEvent(ANIMATION_ITERATION, 'onAnimationIteration');
      registerSimpleEvent(ANIMATION_START, 'onAnimationStart');
      registerSimpleEvent('dblclick', 'onDoubleClick');
      registerSimpleEvent('focusin', 'onFocus');
      registerSimpleEvent('focusout', 'onBlur');
      registerSimpleEvent(TRANSITION_END, 'onTransitionEnd');
    }
```

You can check this [link](https://dev.to/romaintrotard/under-the-hood-of-event-listeners-in-react-4g01) for more information

Comment: The question is not where the listeners are attached to but WHY they're attached, given that majority of those listeners are utterly useless for my app.
Some React's inner working is probably involved but it's still interesting.

Comment: I don't know why all of them are attached but it seems they are attached only in development maybe for purpose of debugging  if you inspect where they are defined you'll see they come from react-dom.develepment.js file